# VB show "The given key was not present in the dictionary" when try to select in database(xampp)

Tags: vb.net

**It shows Error**

> The given key was not present in the dictionary

when I try to check the id and p1 in my database. But I can insert normally.

```
Private Sub checkInsert()
MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server = localhost;userid=root;password=;database=testmg;Character Set=utf8;"
Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
Try
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "select * from car where id= '" & TextBox3.Text & "' and p1= '" & TextBox3.Text & "' "
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    While READER.Read
        count = count + 1
    End While
    If count = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Already")
    ElseIf count > 1 Then
        MsgBox("duplicate")
    Else
        MsgBox("insert correct")
    End If
    MysqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    MysqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Check your connection string, it may be wrong. Maybe something like `Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=;Database=testmg;CharSet=utf8;`

Comment: Your code is _wide open_ for sql injection hacks!  Investigate how to use parameterized queries to prevent this.